# IIS URL Rewrite with multiple query string

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Im really new in URL Rewriting and trying to rewrite / redirect multiple query but seems not working. Since this is the search result and comes with different filtering the queries may vary. For example is some search we may have the query of `t1=something` and in the other we may have `t2=somethingelse` and sometimes we may combine them like: `t1=something&t2=somethingelse`

Im using IIS7 with web.config and here is what I have done so far:
This is my example link

```
www.website.com/search/?t1=first&t2=second
```

I have tried the following and non of them actually worked:
(1)

```
<rewrite> 
    <rules> 
        <rule name="first" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="search/" />
            <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="t1=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="search/{C:1}/" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="second" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="search/" />
            <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="t2=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="search/{C:1}/" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

(2)

```
<rule name="a" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="search2/" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="t1=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="t2=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="search2/{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: It's is a shame nobody has ever replied

Answer (score 1):

Also, this post might provide the answer -

[Tracking Capture Groups Across Conditions setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Tracking_capture_groups_across_conditions_)

EDIT: the example from the link above

Note the **trackAllCaptures**=**true**

```html
<rule name="Back-references with trackAllCaptures set to true">
 <match url="^article\.aspx" >
 <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="p1=([0-9]+)" />
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="p2=([a-z]+)" />  
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx/{C:1}/{C:2}" /> <!-- rewrite action uses back-references to both conditions -->
</rule>
```

Comment: Should be marked as the answer! Worked a treat for me.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd share a link of what I had found -

[possible answer here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1162956.aspx)

Also, to separate multiple parameters you can use a pipe operator. For example, something like this:

parm1=(\w+)|parm2=(\w+)

apply target URL with {C:1} and {C:2}

So, URL like this:

yourapp/list.aspx?parm1=abc&parm2=123

will result in back references as follows - {C:1}=abc and {C:2}=123